# Deploying PostgreSQL cluster in K8s using a StatefulSet

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

Without K8s, creating a PG cluster consists of a series of steps like creating the primary server and add more standby servers, creating a PGBouncer, etc. But in K8s, we can simply create a StatefulSet, specify the number of replicas and assign it to a storage volume. The K8s service LoadBalancer can then act as the PGBouncer and since the deployment is Stateful, no replication configuration would be needed.

But is this clustering concept (specifically for Postgres) even correct? It is simple and easy but does it satisfy all requirements that the traditional PG cluster setup does?